# how to display multiple markers with individual onclick event asociated with them in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers

I need to add multiple markers on the map and when I click on them they have to say the name of the area in a popup or execute another onclick event which can be different for every marker.What would be the best approach to do this, for now what I have is a single marker without any onclick event made in a vector layer.

```
 new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [iconFeature]
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      src: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v6.5.0/examples/data/icon.png'
    })
  })
})
],
```

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_6.5.0_simpleMultipleMarkerExample.html)?

Comment: @geocodezip yes would it be possible for an event to trigger when the marker is clicked , I mean event different than the pop up box like a div element to appear or smt i want to show some info about the point on the side of the map

Comment: how do i get the source for those examples btw

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this on click event:

```
function clickOnFeatures(browserEvent) {
  let coordinate = browserEvent.coordinate;
  let pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate);
  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature) {
    console.log("feature", feature);
    console.log("name", feature.values_.name);
  });
}
```